# Using multiple if/then statements without getting a runtime error

Tags: vba

New to vba and trying to write a simple if/then statement in sequential order to return a value from different sheets.

```
If Cells(4, 4).Value = "water stress" Then
    Cells(15, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(region, ws2.Range("a3:b12"), 2)
End If

If Cells(4, 4).Value = "fire" Then
    Cells(15, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(region, ws3.Range("a3:b12"), 2)
End If
```

When i run the code with only the first if statement, it runs fine.  When I add in the second if statement, I get a run-time error '1004' and am unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class.  I am new, and not sure how to trouble shoot.

Comment: remove the `.worksheetfunction` from the vlookups.  As it is if the vlookup returns null or '#N/A' it throws an error.  without it, the formula will return the n/a as a result.

Comment: This works, and I get an N/A value instead of runtime error.  But after looking over my functions and syntax, it should be returning a value.  Having trouble seeing why it does not return the intended value.

Comment: Without seeing your data and the rest of the code It is hard for me to help you on that one.  One thing you may want to try is put the formula in a cell normally and see what you get, then make sure the the value of `region` truly matches what you're looking for in the data i.e. capitalized the same and no extra spaces.